# Have a question about python module import

Tags: python, intellij-idea, module

Here is my project directory in Intellij

```
parent/
      A/
       test.py
```

In test.py, I have to import a module from parent level of parent folder.

```
import module_needed
```

but module_needed is in this structure:

```
parent_a/
        parent_b/
                py/
                  module_needed
                application/
                           parent/
                                 A/
                                  test.py
```

I tried to add moduled_needed's path to sys.path in test.py. But still cannot find module.
Am I doing wrong? I am using Intellij, is this related to Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

Python import system is quite straightforward. It looks for the packages in folders from `sys.path`. You have to add folder that contains `module_needed` in this case `py` (full path), not path to `module_needed` itself. If it's not there you can add the folder either from the code, directly appending to `sys.path` or with `PYTHONPATH` enviroment variable.

Also try printing `sys.path`, because Intellij might add project root to python path. Then the import statement would be:

```
import parent_a.parent_b.py.module_needed
```

without any modifications.

It might be useful to add the project root, then you won't have to add every single folder separately.